# Indentation of comments in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, format, comments

Eclipse lines up my Java line comments three spaces to the left of the code lines, so that the words of the comment line up to the code, and not the slashes, for example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    Foo foo1 = new Foo();
 // This is a comment.
    Foo foo2 = new Foo();
}
```

I don't want it to do that.  ;o)  I looked in the Java->Code Style->Formatter profile, but I couldn't find what is making it do that (I assumed something on the Indentation or Comments tabs, but I didn't find anything).

Does anyone know where that setting could be hidden so I can get those comments lining up to the code?

Answer (score 5):

"Click on window--> preferences --> type formatter --> Select Formatter in code style under java --> Click on edit (in active profile) --> Unselect "Enable line comment formatting"

[image]

Eclipse doesn't allow to make changes to in-built formatter, you need to create a new profile for your formatter. Refer the link: [How to change in-built formatter settings](http://www.wikihow.com/Change-the-Default-Format-Settings-in-Eclipse). In the new profile just un-select the checkbox mentioned above in screenshot.

Comment: That didn't work, unfortunately ... so, something other than the line comment formatter must be changing the indent on it.

Comment: Check my edit in answer. Hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for taking another crack at it!  Unfortunately, I was already using a new profile, so that didn't help, either.  :-)  What's your next idea?  :-)

Comment: Only disabling the formatter in Save Actions seems to turn off the auto-indent of line comments.

Comment: Is there a way to auto-format the line while pressing *Ctrl+/* or *Ctrl+7* without subsequent line selection and *Ctrl+Shift+F*?